# Best compression method?

Tags: compression

I want to compress a 16GB folder, but what's the best method? tar.gz? tar.bz2 rar? 7z? Would the archive be smaller if I first compressed in a method, then copy the compressed archive to a new folder, then re-compressed in some other method? I need to make it fit on a DVD (output maybe 8.5GB, don't remember) but putting "4370 MB" makes the compressed file be 2.5GB part.

BTW, what's the default compression method on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The default is `gz`. The best results I get with `7z` though.

Here is the results for a 1.4 Gb virtualbox container:

[image]

> Best compression – size in MB:

```
7z 493
rar 523
bz2 592
lzh 607
gz 614
Z 614
zip 614
.arj 615
lzo 737
zoo 890
```

[Source](http://ubuntuguru.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/whats-the-best-file-compression-method/)

[image]

> Install

```
 sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Comment: Thanks, I already installed 7z and rar via Software Center. I'll give a try with 7z.

Comment: Where do these results come from? For every algorithm, the compression ratio and speed depend very much on what you are trying to compress. Try compressing some data coming from `/dev/urandom`: you'll get different results in each try. Or try `/dev/zero`: bzip2 is the winner (for the ratio).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini the link is in the answer so click it!? and like I said: it's based on a 1.4 virtualbox container. I agree that compression depends a lot on what files it are but from a few years of experience 7z seems to be better for the files I tend to have(mostly software and binary data files)

Comment: @Rinzwind: I'm really sorry, I didn't see the _Source_ link.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini it's ok ;) let's hope amanda reports back the results :+

Answer (score 15):

This question is very old, but perhaps somebody finds this solution useful:

Use `rzip`, after `tar`. It first compresses 900 MB large data blocks using a dictionary method, and then it hands the cleaned-up data over to `bzip2`. It is much faster than the other strong compression tools (`bzip2`, `lzma`), and some files it compresses even better than `bzip2` or `lzma`.

Yes, `gz` is the default compression tool on Linux. It is fast, and despite its age it gives still very good results in compressing text files like source code. Another standard tool is `bzip2`, though it is much slower.

**Addition:** lrzip is newer and extends the principle of rzip. It even supports unlimited block sizes, and a choice of compression methods (LZMA, Bzip2, Gzip, LZO, ZPAQ or none). LZMA is the standard. For backup or if you share much data with other Linux/BSD users, it can come in really handy.

Comment: I think you meant 900 kB blocks? 900 MB would be a bit large...

Comment: It actually is 900 MB. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rzip

Answer (score 3):

I opt for a `LZMA`. It has smallest byte overhead and has strong compression ratio. Comparison between ZIP and LZMA:
I've generated two files `seq.txt` with PHP code

```
$s = '0123456789'; $str = ''; for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++) $str .= $s[$i%10].($i%10==9 ? "\n":""); file_put_contents('seq.txt', $str);
```

which holds repeating blocks of 0..9 digits ~ 1Mb of data
and `rnd.txt` with PHP code

```
$s = '0123456789'; $str = ''; for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++) $str .= $s[rand(0,9)].($i%10==9 ? "\n":""); file_put_contents('rnd.txt', $str);
```

which holds random blocks of 0..9 digits ~ 1Mb of data.

**Compression results:**

- seq.txt, rnd.txt - 1100000 bytes
- seq.txt.zip - 2502 bytes
- rnd.txt.zip - 515957 bytes
- seq.txt.lzma - 257 bytes
- rnd.txt.lzma - 484939 bytes

*Compression ratio:*

- ZIP        -> "seq.txt" -> 99.772%
- ZIP        -> "rnd.txt" -> 53.094%
- LZMA  -> "seq.txt" -> 99.976%
- LZMA  -> "rnd.txt" -> 55.914%

So LZMA has compressed sequential data by 0.2% more effectively than ZIP 
and random data 2.8% more effectively than ZIP.

For sure LZMA wins !