# Multi-Core Compression tools

Tags: compression, multi-core

What [compression tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236598/best-compression-method) are available in Ubuntu that can benefit from a multi-core CPU.

Comment: Just for the record, an alternative may be to create independent archives in parallel. So instead of creating myfiles.8core.xz, you create myfiles1.xz to myfiles8.xz in parallel. This will require a dispatch agent. Both approaches have complementary pros and cons.

Comment: Tried to unzip a 7GB file using bzip2 only to find out it is not using all my 8 cores. Read about it and decided to try pbzip2. Still running on just one core. Then I noticed comments saying pbzip2 can only fully parallelize decompression of files it compressed itself. Same comments suggested lbzip2 can fully parallelize on any bz2 file which indeed was true - made almost full use (80-90% of the CPU) of all my cores and it decompressed way faster.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two main tools. `lbzip2` and `pbzip2`. They're essentially different implementations of bzip2 compressors. I've compared them (the output is a tidied up version but you should be able to run the commands)

```
cd /dev/shm  # we do all of this in RAM!
dd if=/dev/urandom of=bigfile bs=1024 count=102400

$ lbzip2 -zk bigfile 
Time: 0m3.596s
Size: 105335428 

$ pbzip2 -zk bigfile
Time: 0m5.738s6
Size: 10532460
```

`lbzip2` appears to be the winner on random data. It's slightly less compressed but much quicker. YMMV.

Comment: looks like a digit is missing from the pbzip2 Size

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is not a great choice of input for benchmarking compression tools, since random data is, by definition, incompressible. That partly explains why in both cases the output file is ~450MiB *bigger* than the input.

Comment: Don't agree with "by definition". Even random data is going to have *some* repetition. But I see your point, real world data will have more.

Comment: *Truly* random data really is incompressible by definition. For pseudorandom data you could, in principle, create a compression scheme that inferred the internal state of the PRNG. However, as far as I'm aware the entropy pool used by `/dev/urandom` uses a combination of keyboard/mouse events, disk seek times, interrupts etc. which is close enough to "true" randomness to be used for cryptographic purposes. That's easily going to be random enough to defeat any standard form of compression.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being really pedantic but truly random data *can* be super-compressible. You could ask a perfect RNG for 32 bits and get `00000000000000000000000000000000`. That's how random works ;) What you're talking about is practical averages. It's *unlikely* you'll generate a 100MB file of just zeros. And I agree with the spirit of what you're saying, I just don't agree with the "by definition" because that isn't the definition (because it's inaccurate).

Comment: When we're judging the performance of different compression methods, what we're really interested in is the *expected* output size for future examples of the kind of data we want to compress. If this data is truly random then it contains no statistical regularity for compression to exploit, so for sequences of *N* random bytes the best we could ever hope for is an expected output length of *N* bytes. For some examples we might do a bit better, for others we might do a bit worse (in practice we almost always do worse), but the *expected* output length stays the same.

Comment: I'll say it again. I don't disagree with what you're saying in general, just the phrasing of "random data is, by definition, incompressible". Rather than repeating yourself (and me), suggest a better set of benchmark source files and I'll rerun the tests against those.

Comment: I mean "random" in the [Kolmogorov sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Kolmogorov_randomness), which is literally defined as incompressibility. There's no universal benchmark for compression since different algorithms work better for different types of data. A good start might be just to pipe it some text, e.g. `wget http://mattmahoney.net/dc/enwik8.zip` to grab 96MB (21MB compressed) of text from Wikipedia. For a much more comprehensive suite of benchmarks, [see here](https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/).

Answer (score 86):

Well, the keyword was **parallel**. After looking for all compression tools that were also **parallel** I found the following:

**PXZ** - Parallel XZ is a compression utility that takes advantage of running LZMA
compression of different parts of an input file on multiple cores and
processors simultaneously. Its primary goal is to utilize all resources to
speed up compression time with minimal possible influence on compression
ratio.

`sudo apt-get install pxz`

**PLZIP** - Lzip is a lossless data compressor based on the LZMA algorithm, with very safe
integrity checking and a user interface similar to the one of gzip or bzip2.
Lzip decompresses almost as fast as gzip and compresses better than bzip2,
which makes it well suited for software distribution and data archiving.

Plzip is a massively parallel (multi-threaded) version of lzip using the lzip
file format; the files produced by plzip are fully compatible with lzip.

Plzip is intended for faster compression/decompression of big files on
multiprocessor machines, which makes it specially well suited for distribution
of big software files and large scale data archiving. On files big enough,
plzip can use hundreds of processors.

`sudo apt-get install plzip`

**PIGZ** - pigz, which stands for Parallel Implementation of GZip, is a fully functional
replacement for gzip that takes advantage of multiple processors and multiple
cores when compressing data.

`sudo apt-get install pigz`

**PBZIP2** - pbzip2 is a parallel implementation of the bzip2 block-sorting file
compressor that uses pthreads and achieves near-linear speedup on SMP
machines. The output of this version is fully compatible with bzip2
v1.0.2 (ie: anything compressed with pbzip2 can be decompressed with
bzip2).

`sudo apt-get install pbzip2`

**LRZIP** - A multithreaded compression program that can achieve very high compression
ratios and speed when used with large files. It uses the combined
compression algorithms of zpaq and lzma for maximum compression, lzo
for maximum speed, and the long range redundancy reduction of rzip.
It is designed to scale with increases with RAM size, improving
compression further. A choice of either size or speed optimizations
allows for either better compression than even lzma can provide, or
better speed than gzip, but with bzip2 sized compression levels.

`sudo apt-get install lrzip`

A small Compression Benchmark (Using the test Oli created):

ORIGINAL FILE SIZE - 100 MB
PBZIP2 - 101 MB (1% Bigger)
PXZ - 101 MB (1% Bigger)
PLZIP - 102 MB (1% Bigger)
LRZIP - 101 MB (1% Bigger)
PIGZ - 101 MB (1% Bigger)

A small Compression Benchmark (Using a Text file):

ORIGINAL FILE SIZE - 70 KB Text File
PBZIP2 - 16.1 KB (23%)
PXZ - 15.4 KB (22%)
PLZIP - 15.5 KB (22.1%)
LRZIP - 15.3 KB (21.8%)
PIGZ - 17.4 KB (24.8%)

Comment: Examples would be great.

Comment: @earthmeLon Read the answer by Oli which mentions how to create the example file. Then proceed with the commands I used.

Comment: I hope the output of these are inter-compatible. i.e. output from `lrzip` can be uncompressed using `pbzip2`, for instance.

Comment: Great list and thanks! In addition, unless you are searching for general set of replacements, I would make sure to test your usecase. The speeds and compression ratios are going to depend a bit on what you are compressing. I was just using bzip2 and have just tested all the options above. pbzip2 compresses 4x faster for <1% bigger. The best compression was lzma, but it took 8x std bzip2, xz was about the same as std bzip2 for time with about 6% better compression. pigz gave the crappy compression you'd expect, but was 32x faster than std bzip2 (1sec vs 32secs)!!!

Comment: Cool, now I am using pxz instead of gz and get a additional decrease in size of the compressed file of nearly 50 %. I get my mysqldump-data, pxz and an upload to an other server in the same time. (170 MB Data => 23 MB.gz, now 11 MB .xz)

Answer (score 25):

### Update:

[XZ Utils](http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD) supports multi-threaded compression since v5.2.0, it was originally mistakenly documented as being multi-threaded decompression.

For example: `tar -cf - source | xz --threads=0 > destination.tar.xz`

Comment: You can also run `export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0"`  and then just use your usual tar call, i.e. `tar cJf target.tar.xz source`.

Comment: wow! why is this not the default?

Comment: `tar -cvf ...` to be verbose

Comment: on my Linux `xz --threads=0` is actually utilizing 3/8 threads, so not really parallel, `pixz` or as some people said `pxz` is utilizing 5/8, so I would suggest using `pxz` for better results.

Comment: xz it built-in on both RHEL and Ubuntu, so this wins for me.

Answer (score 11):

In addition the nice summary above (thanks Luis), these days folks might also want to consider PIXZ, which according to it's README (Source: https://github.com/vasi/pixz -- I haven't verified the claims myself) has some advantages over PXZ.

```
[Compared to PIXZ, PXZ has these advantages and disadvantages:]

    * Simpler code
    * Uses OpenMP instead of pthreads
    * Uses streams instead of blocks, not indexable
    * Uses temp files and doesn't combine them until the whole file is compressed, high disk/memory usage
```

In other words, PIXZ is supposedly more memory and disk efficient, and has an optional indexing feature that speeds up decompression of individual components of compressed tar files.

Comment: However, it is my understanding that `pixz` archives are not compatible with standard `xz` format, the way `pxz` would be.

Comment: @Mxx: The file formats are compatible. `pixz` can decompress `xz` archives and `xz` can decompress `pixz` archives. However, the command line options on `xz` and `pixz` differ.

Comment: Indexable files are a big win for `pixz`.

Answer (score 8):

**[Zstandard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstandard)** supports multi-threading since [v1.2.0](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases)¹. It is a very fast compressor and decompressor intended to replace gzip and it can also compress as efficient (if not better) as LZMA2/XZ on its highest levels.

You have to use [one of these releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=zstd), or compile the latest version from source to get these benefits. Luckily it doesn't pull in a lot of dependencies.

There was also a 3rd party pzstd in v1.1.0 of zstd.

Answer (score 5):

[lzop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lzop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) may also be a viable option, although it's single-threaded.

It uses the *very* fast [lempel-ziv-oberhumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer) compression algorithm which is 5-6 times faster than gzip in my observation.

Note: Although it's not multi-threaded yet, it will probably outperform pigz on 1-4 core systems. That's why I decided to post this even if it doesn't directly answer your question. Try it, it may solve your CPU bottleneck problem while using only one CPU and  compressing a little worse. I found it often to be a better solution than, e.g pigz.

Comment: Isn't it just better at decompressing? Compressing takes about the same (or worse) than gzip

Comment: I can also testify that [lzop](http://www.lzop.org/) is super fast. [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/proxmox-v) uses lzop for backup of virtual machines by default.

Comment: [lz4](http://www.lz4.org) is even faster (and has a multi-threaded version).

Answer (score 4):

It is not really an answer, but I think it is relevant enough to share my benchmarks comparing speed of `gzip` and `pigz` on a real HW in a real life scenario. As `pigz` is the multithreaded evolution I personally have chosen to use from now on.

Metadata:

- Hardware used: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz` (4c/8t) + Nvme SSD
- GNU/Linux distribution: `Xubuntu 17.10 (artful)`
- `gzip` version: `1.6`
- `pigz` version: `2.4`
- The file being compressed is *9.25 GiB SQL* dump

**`gzip` quick**

```
time gzip -1kN ./db_dump.sql

real    1m22,271s
user    1m17,738s
sys     0m3,330s
```

**`gzip` best**

```
time gzip -9kN ./db_dump.sql 

real    10m6,709s
user    10m2,710s
sys     0m3,828s
```

**`pigz` quick**

```
time pigz -1kMN ./db_dump.sql 

real    0m26,610s
user    1m55,389s
sys     0m6,175s
```

**`pigz` best** (no `zopfli`)

```
time pigz -9kMN ./db_dump.sql 

real    1m54,383s
user    14m30,435s
sys     0m5,562s
```

**`pigz` + `zopfli` algorithm**

```
time pigz -11kMN ./db_dump.sql 

real    171m33,501s
user    1321m36,144s
sys     0m29,780s
```

As a bottomline I would not recommend the `zopfli` algorithm since the compression took tremendous amount of time for a not-that-significant amount of disk space spared.

Resulting file sizes:

- *best*s: 1309M
- *quick*s: 1680M
- *zopfli*: 1180M

Answer (score 3):

The LZMA2 compressor of [p7zip](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/p7zip) [image: Install p7zip] uses both cores on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant Arch Wiki entry:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Utilizing_multiple_cores_on_compression

```bsh
# lzma compression
xz --threads=0

# drop-in parallel gzip replacement
# -p/--processes flag can be used to employ less cores
pigz

# drop-in parallel bzip2 replacement
# -p# flag can be used to employ less cores
# (note: no space between the -p and number of cores)
pbzip2

# modern zstd compression
# is used to build Arch packages by default
# since somewhere 2020
zstd --threads=0
```